# HttpClient Выбор IP alias

Tags: c#, .net

Каким образом я могу привязать `HttpClient` к определённому дополнительному IP адресу (alias), если их несколько на сетевом интерфейсе? Нашёл следующее решение:

```
public static HttpClient GetHttpClient(IPAddress address)
{
    if (IPAddress.Any.Equals(address))
        return new HttpClient();

    SocketsHttpHandler handler = new SocketsHttpHandler();

    handler.ConnectCallback = async (context, cancellationToken) =>
    {
        Socket socket = new Socket(SocketType.Stream, ProtocolType.Tcp);

        socket.Bind(new IPEndPoint(address, 0));

        socket.NoDelay = true;

        try
        {
            await socket.ConnectAsync(context.DnsEndPoint, cancellationToken).ConfigureAwait(false);

            return new NetworkStream(socket, true);
        }
        catch
        {
            socket.Dispose();

            throw;
        }
    };

    return new HttpClient(handler);
}
```

Однако использовать класс `SocketsHttpHandler` в .NET Framework 4.7.2 (целевая платформа для моего проекта) не представляется возможным - он доступен только в .NET Core 2.1 и более:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Может есть иные пути это реализовать? Мне важно использовать именно `HttpClient` и желательно обойтись без сторонних библиотек.

Comment: в .NET Framework 4.x нужно использовать `ServicePointManager`, он управляет старичком `WebRequestHandler` для `HttpClient`, хотя там может и не быть того что вам нужно. Но я вообще не понимаю, что за задачу вы решаете. Странный какой-то вопрос. `HttpClient` не привязывается ни к каким адресам, он клиент. Он не может принимать запросы, этим занимается `HttpListener`, а может только отправлять их. Хотя может я чего-то не понимаю. Еще более удивительно - писать что-либо под Framework 4.x :). `WebRequestHandler` ничего нового не поддерживает и работает сильно медленнее, чем `SocketsHttpHandler`.

Comment: [StandardSocketsHttpHandler](https://github.com/TalAloni/StandardSocketsHttpHandler)?

Comment: @aepot _"HttpClient не привязывается ни к каким адресам, он клиент. Он не может принимать запросы, этим занимается HttpListener, а может только отправлять их."_ - Речь идёт о ситуации, когда на сервере к сетевому интерфейсу привязано несколько IP-адресов, нужно выбрать 1 конкретный, с которого запрос будет отправлен в сеть. _"Еще более удивительно - писать что-либо под Framework 4.x :)"_ - Почему же?

Comment: @AlexanderPetrov Находил это решение, я бы хотел обойтись без сторонних библиотек, но если не будет выбора, буду использовать именно его.

Comment: Ничего не прояснилось, а зачем его вообще привязывать? Есть таблица маршрутизации на сервере, которая в зависимости от целевого адреса шлет пакеты в нужный интерфейс. То есть если вы хотите поменять маршрут по умолчанию, отредактируйте таблицу маршрутизации. Зачем эти костыли в коде, если вопрос, если я его правильно понял, решается сисадминскими средствами?

Comment: По поводу Framework 4, вы пишете серверное приложение для сервера, на который .NET 6 Runtime не можете установить? Вдвойне удивительно. С клиентскими приложениями в каких-то случаях легаси можно понять требованием к совместимости с какими-нибудь Windows XP.

Comment: Мне нужно обращаться в сеть с разных IP адресов. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IP_aliasing

Comment: _"По поводу Framework 4, вы пишете серверное приложение для сервера, на который .NET 6 Runtime не можете установить?"_ - Могу, но проект изначально создавался под .NET Framework 4.7, поэтому не хочу менять. Возникла потребность внести небольшие изменения.

Comment: Если проект не большой, портировать не долго. Тем более плюшки в виде прироста в производительности для сервера должны быть весьма ценными. Я даже не уверен, что портирование займет больше времени, чем втыкание костылей в фреймворк. Сегодня StandardSocketsHttpHandler, а завтра что? :) В общем, насколько я вижу, с помощью `WebRequestHandler` или его связанной начинки то что вам нужно, сделать не получится.

Comment: Возможно вы и правы, я подумаю над этим. А пока давайте всё же вернёмся к самому вопросу.

Comment: Может быть кто то другой на этом форуме столкнётся с такой проблемой, а переход на .NET 6 не будет выходом.

Comment: Окей, давайте по-другому подъедем к вопросу. Внутри `WebRequestHandler` сидит `HttpWebRequest`. И [насколько я вижу](https://docs.microsoft.com/ru-ru/dotnet/api/system.net.httpwebrequest), ничего подобного с локалэнпоинтами в его API нет. Приехали.

Comment: То есть по всей видимости без сторонних библиотек вроде той что предложил @AlexanderPetrov ничего не выйдет.

Comment: Всё верно. Можете конечно сами портировать [SocketsHttpHandler](https://github.com/dotnet/runtime/blob/main/src/libraries/System.Net.Http/src/System/Net/Http/SocketsHttpHandler/SocketsHttpHandler.cs), тогда библиотека будет не сторонней. :)